# Cannot create new projects in Platform IO VS-Code plugin

Tags: visual-studio-code, platformio

After a fresh install of VS Code and PlatformIO I get the following error when simply trying to open a new project. (Note: I'm using Windows 10)

***Could not initialize project
PIO Core Call Error: "DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found."***

I'd really love to start using this tool becasue it seems very useful. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Wonderful news, I have found a simple fix! As usual it is due to yet another one of Microsoft's latest Anti-Features. This time it's Cortatna, that POS I never use but has been quietly haunting my file system for the past year.

Note: this was discovered after investigating numerous other issues with my file system, all of which appear to have the same cause

**Option 1**, Stay in the dream:

1. Press  Ctrl + Shift + Esc keys together to Open Task manager.
2. Now, Locate Cortana and do a Right Click on it and Choose End task.
   Doing this will restart the Cortana process and will Fix the issue... (Temporarily??)

**Option 2**, (I personally did not try this one):

Install KB4532695 update to fix this
Microsoft have released KB4532695 update which seems to fix this issue for the PC affected by this bug. Just download and install KB4532695 from this official Microsoft website.

Reference:
https://thegeekpage.com/how-to-fix-file-explorer-search-not-working-in-windows-10/

**Option 3**: Shatter the grand illusion and wake up from the nightmare all together.

To **remove Cortana** from Windows 10, use these steps:

1. Open Start.
2. Search for PowerShell, right-click the top result, and select the Run as administrator option.
3. Type the following command to uninstall Cortana from Windows 10 and press Enter:
   `Get-AppxPackage -allusers Microsoft.549981C3F5F10 | Remove-AppxPackage`

Reference: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-uninstall-cortana-windows-10-may-2020-update
Also, I appears as though MS will not let me uninstall their malware so to get rid of Cortana may require even more work.

Not sure, but you may need to run Step one first if you encounter issues.